# Read txt file and display contents as images javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

can you please kindly assist me with this code? I am trying to populate a list of images when a button is clicked.. The `screenShotsList.txt` consists of files names such as:

out1.png
out2.png
out3.png
out4.png
out5.png
out6.png
out7.png
out8.png

Right now, my problem is idk the syntax to display my array as a group of images and the code does not work when a button is clicked.

Here is the code I have so far..

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("button").click(function(){
var file = "C:/newbots/ctfuPoster/data/screenShotsList.txt";
function getFile(){
$.get(file,function(txt){
var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
// Equivalent: $(document.createElement('img'))
var img = $('<img id="dynamic">'); 
img.attr('src', lines[i]);
img.appendTo('#imagediv');
}
}); 
}
}); 
</script>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You forgot to mention what the problem is. "Help me with my code" isn't specific enough and you risk having your question closed as "too broad".

Comment: 1: You probably get an error because you are not allowed to access local files (`c:/newbots..`). 2: an ID needs to be unique, so in your loop the `img` can't have that ID.

Comment: @cr0ss it's an alrternate text mood if that makes sense, kind-of italics.

Comment: @alou haha I know. I'm just not sure why. Check out where the tags are.

Comment: s.o. was telling me to use the <i> tag to wrap my code, it was my fault, probably a misunderstanding. 

Right now when I click the button, nothing happens. Also, I do not know how to format the code to display the results in a img src tag

Comment: Thank you spender, I will look into your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this example you have a simple html page with a little script

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
            url : "screen.TXT",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
            console.log(data)
               var lines = data.split(",")
                for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                    var img = $('<img class="dynamic">'); 
                    img.attr('src', lines[i]);
                    img.appendTo('#imageDiv');
                }
            }
        });         
     });
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="imageDiv"></div>    
<input value="clickMe" type="button" id="button">    
</body>
</html>
```

For the operation of the script i created a simple text file with the following structure and name screen.txt.
 This text file contains links to pictures of lorempixel.com must be at the same level of html page
screen.txt file:

```
http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-300-300-7.jpg,
http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-300-300-9.jpg,
http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-300-300-2.jpg
```

For online working example visit: [this page](http://www.devimadesign.com/test/aa.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm going to try this out now. Have a great day :-) I can't upvote you because I'm new.

Comment: @user3664782 uou can't upvote but you can flag in green my answer ;), thanks